# JMeter load test, JSON request with unique content

Tags: json, jmeter

I need to do some loading testing for the REST service. I have not had an experience with it before and decided to use JMeter for my purposes.

The main goal to create several test suits which will send different kind of requests simultaneously. I figured out how it works, but what is the current challenge I have:

I would like to have, for example, 5 threads. Each thread will send about 500 unique request, it will be enough for my purposes... But the problem is that I need to have different JSON content for each request (username/password). What is the easiest way how I can optimise my time on doing such repeatable work in order not to create manually 2000+ request with different content) I saw in documentation that there is a 'User Variable' functionality, looks like it provides such ability, but I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of pre-defined username/password pairs you can use [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) which will read file with user credentials and use them as variables.

If you just need to randomize your data JMeter provides [_*Random()*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [_RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) functions.

If you need to extract value from server response and construct your JSON request body based on previous result there is a [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via plugin.

Comment: Yes, CSV Data Set config is really what I need, but it is not clear for me how to configure it.. Because the only param that I send in the request is whole JSon: http://cl.ly/image/1j1J1I0C1G0S. Or it could be done another way?

Comment: Uh, I got it to work, initially when I tried it, I have invalid path, that is why I was disappointed... Tnx for the help